# Show custom message when no rows selected in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an exam about PL/SQL in a couple of days and while reviewing my exercises I found one which I can't seem to solve. I have to make a procedure which returns all department names linked to a given country_id. When there are no department names linked to the country_id the procedure has to return something like 'nothing found'. I'm having trouble with this custom error message.

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_dept(p_land_id IN countries.country_id%TYPE)
AS
 v_countries NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FOR rec IN (SELECT d.department_name 
        FROM departments d
        INNER JOIN locations l ON d.location_id=l.location_id
        INNER JOIN countries c ON c.country_id=l.country_id
        WHERE c.country_id=p_land_id) 
 LOOP
  IF rec.department_name IS NOT NULL THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.department_name);
  ELSIF rec.department_name IS NULL THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Er zijn geen departmenten gevestigd in het land met id '||p_land_id);
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
END country_dept;
```

How can I print a message if the query doesn't find any data?

Comment: Hint: count how many times you've been round the loop...

Comment: That did the trick, thank you sir

Comment: Or a boolean flag is probably cleaner if you don't care about the actual number, as in the suggested dupe target.